# Youtube video in VideoView

Tags: android

I want to play a remote video in a Videoview. Anybody knows a good free server to load my videos in it to later stream in a videoview? Is possible to see in a videoview Youtube videos? I have see another questions but I don´t understand. Anybody can put a example to play a Youtube video or remote video for another server in a videoview?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check [android-youtube-player](http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/), a project to make YouTube videos play in a `VideoView`. The usage instructions and sample `Activity` code is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely stream video directly into a VideoView without a problem, and you set it up normally as well:

```
Uri pathtoVideo = Uri.parse(path);
videoView.setVideoURI(pathToVideo);
```

However, there are a lot of videos on Youtube that aren't mobile-friendly, and will end up throwing a "This Video Cannot Be Played" error.

The MediaPlayer on Android can only play "progressive streamable contents" which basically means: 1. the movie atom has to precede all the media data atoms. 2. The clip has to be reasonably interleaved. If it doesn't, you'll get the error I mentioned above.

Comment: Do you know how get the 3gp link of a video of Youtube? Thank you

Comment: That I can't help you with, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the YouTube API for android?  I recently posted a tutorial on how to use the video and thumbnail views from the API [here](http://androiddev101.com/episode-12-youtube-it-all-night-long/)